# circular relation between reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a person form that has some basic properties and also has a node called relatives

```
    let personFormGroup = this.fb.group({
        id: new FormControl(),
        gender: new FormControl(),
        ...        
        relatives: this.createRelatives(),
});
```

the problem is that Relatives is an array of RelativePerson which has some unique basic properties and also a Person inside it

```
    let relativeFormGroup = this.fb.group({
            id: [null], // Initialize with default values or null
            relation_type: [''],
            ...
            Person: this.createPersonControl(),
            comments: ['']
        });
```

the problem is I can't duplicate either one cuz that's bad practice and even if I want both of them have lots of properties, so how can I handle such circular relation where I can create a person add relativePeople

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person form must contain an empty relative array, so when you add a FormGroup for relatives, it will contain persons without relatives, and use patch style in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Use id only to reference the person

```
let relativeFormGroup = this.fb.group({
  id: [null], // Initialize with default values or null
  relation_type: [''],
  ...
  personId: [null],
  comments: ['']
});`
```

Edit:

Or create an empty FormArray within `createRelatives`as per comments.

Comment: they want the form to be able to accept Person Objects that are not in the DB yet "create person if it doesn't exist" so I kind of have to keep it. is there a way "flag or something" to prevent the creation of 'relatives' node if Person is inside relativeForm ?

Comment: How does `createRelatives` look like?

Comment: it returns a FormArray with one relativeFormGroup inside it

Comment: Creating an empty FormArray should help.

Comment: you mean down the loop, having an empty FormArray would break the cycle. If so I think this could work. THANKS